# How do I avoid collision with the launchpad tower?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I keep losing boosters to the launchpad tower. Is there any way to place my rocket further away from it?

Comment: ... wha... how many boosters do you *have*?

Comment: @Tacroy 12, but I've managed to cram more on on other rockets...

Comment: I'll tell you what I told @GnomeSlice: you're doing it wrong

Comment: @MBraedley I'm aware of that, but in what way?

Comment: I wasn't aware there *was* a "wrong" way to do KSP -- just that some ways were more "hilarious" than others...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As of .19, there is no more launch tower.  Until the demo gets updated as well, though, this still applies to it.**

There's no way to move your rocket away from the launch tower, but what you CAN do is build AWAY from it.  When in the VAB, there's a hallway on one side.  The side facing the door on the **left** is the side facing the launch tower.

I have helpfully drawn a diagram to illustrate this point:
[image]

As long as you don't build too close to the outer edge of the VAB circle, you'll be alright:
[image]

This far out will work.  Adding more boosters to the side of the central engine will clip the side of the launch tower.

Theoretically, you COULD move the central point of the rocket out of the center of the launch circle, but that may be more effort than it's worth.